# List of programming languages for mobile devices

Tags: programming-languages, mobile

What are the programming languages supported by mobile devices? Is there some list or can anyone make a list of some?

I don't what to search, but I as able to find 3:

- .NET
- Flash Lite
- java

Are these the most used? What other languages are there that are used quite often?

Comment: Assume that pretty much any language is supported by *some* mobile device. Programmers are an inventive bunch. Do you want to ask a more specific, targeted question?

Comment: Is there some that are used more often? Or more common to see around? Besides of java...

Comment: It makes more sense to ask yourself what device you wish to target, and *then* to find out what languages area available.  Or do you have a language in mind, and wish to find out what devices support it?

Comment: @Ben: I don't want to know a specific device. I want to know what is most used for most of devices...

Comment: That won't help you as a language isn't important. It's the libraries that you will need to use most times, and those differ by device or operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard answering this question, because "used most" implies the need for some kind of statistics to back it up. Instead I present you with some examples.

Objective-C is more or less the default language for iPhone and iPad applications. Flash is verboten, but I think Adobe AIR is allowed, and MonoTouch (.NET)

Java is commonly used for Android applications, although you can probably use any language with a JVM application, so technically it could be Scala, Rhino, Jython.

You can use Lua, Python and more on Android with a program made for running scripts, released by Google outside of Market I think.

Nokia Maego and Symbian favours C++ if I recall correctly but I wouldn't be surprised if you could use virtually anything provided it is runnable on the platform.

Anyhow it varies a lot, and depending on the OS vendor, you can often use a multitude of languages as long as they allow it.

Comment: Adobe AIR and MonoTouch aren't languages per se, but it will give you a pointer as to what you can use.

Comment: Thank you! That is very enlightening.